# Current recommendation for enabling session in Azure Websites for Session variables and TempData?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a  MVC3, ASP.NET 4.5 web application deployed on Azure Websites, using SQL Azure.

Currently I am using some "inproc" Session variables which I need to remove since I am going to start using multi website instances. I could just store the Session variable values in the SQL Azure DB, but I am also using TempData, which also uses Session state, "under the bonnet". Due to TempData use, I do need to implement an "out of proc" session solution.

I have seen some recommendation for using AppFabric caching, but I am unsure whether this is still current, and whether it is correct for Azure websites.

Also my development setup is on a Windows 7 machine with SQL Server 2008 R2. So a solution should be transferable with minimum pain.

There is also a "thread agility" issue with session variables, and a open source solution has been created using REDIS caching, but I have no experience of this, or REDIS. See: [GitHub site](https://github.com/angieslist/AL-Redis)

So thoughts I have are:

1) Angieslist/AL-redis custom provider, see: [GITHUB link](https://github.com/angieslist/AL-Redis) . Not entirely sure that this can be used in a Azure Websites application.

2) Appfabric. Not sure if this is relevant or current for Azure Websites.

3) SQL Azure session provider.

4) Azure Table storage.

5) Use a custome TempData provider to persist via cookies ie https://www.nuget.org/packages/BrockAllen.CookieTempData.dll/1.2.2, and then remove other session variables.

I would be very grateful for advice on a good Azure Websites session implementation mechanism which is simple. My data is pretty simple. I think I have one object which I quess I will need to serialize, probably via Json.NET

Comment: I would suggest Redis Cache as along as you are ok with leveraging a Preview feature in your solution. Otherwise, Websites does support sticky sessions (client->server affinity) which in most cases will route the user to the same machine they were using before so the machine should still have their session details.

Comment: Thanks for this. Our site is in production so "Preview feature" may not be the wisest choice. I need to read up on sticky sessions, as I was a little unaware of this, but basically "inproc" will work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have more than one instance of an Azure Web Site, sticky sessions are enabled by default by the load balancer.  This means that a user will be directed to the same instance (server) and that you'll be able to use session state in your app.

Comment: Interesting. Obviously I want to free up the LB to choose whichever instance is least busy, so perhaps 5) is best, but no need of custom TempData provider due to sticky sessions. Thoughts?

Comment: Am I correct here, when one has no session variables, and all TempData variables have expired, then the LB is free to go to whatever instance it chooses?

Comment: This blog post from Erez Benari, Program Manager Azure Web Sites, explains how to disable server affinity but most important, he explains how the load balancer works.

Comment: Thanks for this. However I think you missed the link to the blog.

Comment: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2013/11/18/disabling-arrs-instance-affinity-in-windows-azure-web-sites/ . Is this it?

Comment: Doh!  It's too early...sorry about that.  Yep, you got the right one.

Comment: A most interesting article. Also confirms my suspicions about how sticky sessions could be kept open, and how benefits of multi instances can be compromised. Could end up with a very busy instance and the other being hardly used which defeats the purpose. So I guess it is a bit of a stop gap. With TempData, I wonder whether you would still get this stickiness as the session should have disappeared once the TempData has expired, which is after the redirection.

Comment: Both answers correct, but can only award to one person, and this would be the short term answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may also find the Distributed Caching section (Ch 12) of this ebook helpful http://aka.ms/CloudApps_PDF

Comment: thank you for this. Both answers were correct for me, but can only award to one person :( However I think your answer will have benefit, longer term. So thanks.